# For Loop in Javascript (With Fiddle)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can also use jquery if you want. I'm trying to enable/disable the `start,pause,stop,kill` buttons based on the combination of array.

In sum:

- If the array is all up (started) -> I can pause, stop, kill
- If the array is all down (stopped) -> I can start, kill
- If the array is all pause (paused) -> I can start, stop, kill
- If the array is all created (created) -> I can start, kill

Now comes the tricky part.

- If the array is all stopped or paused -> I can start, kill
- If the array is all started or paused -> I can stop, kill

I think that's it.

My solution only takes in account the last element. I need something to compare all the array first.

Any help?

```js
var array = ["up","down","up","pause","up","pause","down","created"];
//Booleans
var start = false, stop = false, pause = false, kill = false;

for(let i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
  var element = array[i];
 console.log(element);
  if(element == "up") {
   stop = true;
    pause = true;
    kill = true;
    start = false;
  }
  else if (element == "down") {
   stop = false;
    kill = true;
    start = true;
    pause = false;
  }
  else if (element == "created") {
   stop = false;
    pause = false;
    kill = true;
    start = true;
  }
  else if (element == "pause") {
   stop = true;
    pause = false;
    kill = true;
    start = true;
  }
}
console.log(start + " // " + pause + " // " + stop + " // " + kill);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to check every element fulfills the test.

```
if (array.every(x => x == "up")) {
  //All elements are up
}
```

```js
var array = ["up", "down", "up", "pause", "up", "pause", "down", "created"];
//Booleans
var start = false,
  stop = false,
  pause = false,
  kill = false;

if (array.every(x => x == "up")) {
  stop = true;
  pause = true;
  kill = true;
  start = false;
} else if (array.every(x => x == "down")) {
  stop = false;
  kill = true;
  start = true;
  pause = false;
} else if (array.every(x => x == "created")) {
  stop = false;
  pause = false;
  kill = true;
  start = true;
} else if (array.every(x => x == "pause")) {
  stop = true;
  pause = false;
  kill = true;
  start = true;
}

console.log(start + " // " + pause + " // " + stop + " // " + kill);
```

Comment: this would work for my second part too with the or statement?

Comment: @user9299353, Yes it can. You just need to change the test condition i.e.  `array.every(x => x == "down" || x == "pause")`

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this the other way round as it's more elegant. Basically:

- One `up`, means you can't `start`
- One `down`, means you can't `stop` or `pause`
- One `pause`, means you can't `pause`
- One `created`, means you can't `stop` or `pause`

Once you've looped through the array switching off what you can't do, your left with what you can do:

```js
var disabler = {
    up: {start: false}, // started
    down: {stop: false, pause: false}, // stopped
    pause: {pause: false}, // paused
    created: {stop: false, pause: false} // created
};

var states = ["up", "down", "up", "pause", "up", "pause", "down", "created"];
var filled = states.length > 0;
var actions = {start: filled, stop: filled, pause: filled, kill: filled};
if (filled) {
    actions.kill = states.every(function (state) {
        Object.assign(actions, disabler[state]); // disable actions for state
        return actions.start || actions.stop || actions.pause; //break on false
    });
}

console.log(actions); // {start: false, stop: false, pause: false, kill: false}
```

I've used [Array.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) so that the loop stops if all actions have been disabled, which in this case is after the second iteration.

Comment: Your `kill` actually doesn't give the correct result. Though it appears in all the qualifying criteria, the criteria is not exhaustive. It should be `true` only if all the items in the list match or are all  either ("down" and "pause") or ("up" and "pause").

Answer (score 0):

You should totally use bit flags for this. Makes it clean, short and fast.

```js
var array = ["up", "down", "up", "pause", "up", "pause", "down", "created"];

// Define the flags
const flags = {
  up:      1 << 0,
  down:    1 << 1,
  pause:   1 << 2,
  created: 1 << 3,
};

// Set the flags
var f = array.reduce((f, s) => f | flags[s], 0);

// Interpret the flags
var pause = f == flags.up;

var stop  = f == flags.up    ||
            f == flags.pause ||
            f == (flags.pause | flags.up);

var start = f == flags.down    ||
            f == flags.pause   ||
            f == flags.created ||
            f == (flags.pause | flags.down);

var kill  = pause || stop || start;

console.log(start + " // " + pause + " // " + stop + " // " + kill);
```

---

You could also shorten it with an `hasOnly` function that checks if the flag(s) provided are in the state and none others.

```js
var array = ["up", "down", "up", "pause", "up", "pause", "down", "created"];

// Define the flags
const flags = {
  up:      1 << 0,
  down:    1 << 1,
  pause:   1 << 2,
  created: 1 << 3,
};

// Set the flags
var f = array.reduce((f, s) => f | flags[s], 0);

// Interpret the flags
var pause = f == flags.up;
var stop  = hasOnly(f, flags.pause | flags.up);
var start = f == flags.created || hasOnly(f, flags.pause | flags.down);
var kill  = pause || stop || start;

console.log(start + " // " + pause + " // " + stop + " // " + kill);

function hasOnly(f, mask) {
   return (f & ~mask) == 0 && (f & mask) != 0
}
```

Comment: I thought about doing it this way but it's not very readable.

Comment: @DJDaveMark: I personally find it to be more readable and understandable. You don't need to interpret an algorithm to see what each allowed action means. It's just spelled out. Though I'd consider yours to be the next best in clarity.

Answer (score -1):

Although, my codes are bit lengthy and not elegant, it should solve your cases..

```js
var array = ["up","down","up","pause","up","pause","down","created"];
//Booleans
var start = false, stop = false, pause = false, kill = false;
var up = false, down = false, paused = false, created = false;

for(let i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
  var element = array[i];
 
  if(element == "up") {
    up = true;
  }
  else if (element == "down") {
   down = true;
  }
  else if (element == "created") {
   created = true;
  }
  else if (element == "pause") {
    paused = true;
  }
}

// all are up

if( up && !down && !created && !paused){
    pause = true;
    stop = true;
    kill = true;
}

// all are pause

if( !up && !down && !created && paused){
    start = true;
    stop = true;
    kill = true;
}

// all are either down or created
if( !up && !paused && (( down || created ) && !( down && created ))){
    start = true;
    kill = true;
}

// all are either down or paused
if( !up && !created && (down && paused)){
    start = true;
    kill = true;
}

// all are either up or paused
if( !down && !created && (up && paused)){
    stop = true;
    kill = true;
}


console.log(start + " // " + pause + " // " + stop + " // " + kill);
```